# How to connect SQLServer using JDBC connection in AWS Glue

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, aws-glue

I want to load data from Glue into SQL Server using the JDBC connection option, after providing JDBC URL format

```
jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=db_name, User name, and Password
```

, while testing the connection I'm getting an error that is given below. 
Can anyone help me where I went wrong?

```
2019-11-13 09:29:01 INFO  CatalogClient:682 - Got connection 'SQLServer' info from Catalog with url: jdbc:sqlserver://32.238.81.66:1433/Glue_Test
2019-11-13 09:29:02 INFO  CatalogClient:718 - JDBC configuration for connection Staken QLServer: JDBCConfiguration(url=jdbc:sqlserver://32.238.81.66:1433/Glue_Test, hostname=32.238.81.66, port=1433, databaseVendor=sqlserver, databaseVersion=null, connectionName=SQLServer, path=Glue_Test, subnetId=subnet-3d416a13, availabilityZone=us-east-1b, securityGroups=[sg-c4d3929b], enforceSSL=false, customJDBCCert=null, skipCustomJDBCCertValidation=null, customJDBCCertString=null)
2019-11-13 09:29:02 INFO  JdbcConnection:46 - Starting connecter. driver SQLServerDriver:2
2019-11-13 09:29:02 INFO  JdbcConnection:64 - Attempting to connect with SSL host matching: jdbc:sqlserver://32.238.81.66:1433;database={Glue_Test};hostNameInCertificate=32.238.81.66
2019-11-13 09:29:17 INFO  JdbcConnection:73 - SSL connection to data store using host matching failed. Retrying without host matching.
2019-11-13 09:29:17 INFO  JdbcConnection:87 - Attempting to connect with SSL: jdbc:sqlserver://32.238.81.66:1433;database={Glue_Test}
2019-11-13 09:29:32 INFO  JdbcConnection:92 - SSL connection to data store failed. Retrying without SSL.
2019-11-13 09:29:32 INFO  JdbcConnection:106 - Attempting to connect without SSL: jdbc:sqlserver://32.238.81.66:1433;database={Glue_Test}
Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. The TCP/IP connection to the host 32.238.81.66, port 1433 has failed.

 Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.". Exiting with error code 30
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you could upload the code snippet of how exactly you are trying to access the database from glue script.

Answer (score 0):

Glue connections works very similar to how you allow communication in any VPC. Glue will launch an elastic network interface to facilitate communication with your database. First thing you can test, launch an instance in the same subnet and security group  as your database and do 'nc -vz dbendpoint port'. This confirms that the security groups is allowing to communicate on that port if you can get a successful connection.

From glue make use of the same subnet and security group this should work with no issues. You can also make use of this as a reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/start-connecting.html